# Wait for fetch function to complete before firing another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, fetch

Currently the **console.log(this.detaliiMP)** return an empty array. What I want is to wait until the **getData()** function fetched the data into **detaliiMP** array and then to log out to the console the array filled with data.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5kfcaw?file=src%2FApp.vue)

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      detaliiMP: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      fetch("https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=5")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.detaliiMP = data)
        .catch(err => console.error(err.message))
    },
    showData() {
      this.getData()
      console.log(this.detaliiMP)
    }
  },
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="getData">Get Data</button>

  <button @click="showData">Console LogOut</button>

  <p v-for="item in detaliiMP">{{ item.first_name }}</p>
</div>
```

I was trying with **async/await** but clearly I did something wrong, because is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's async/await matter.

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      detaliiMP: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getData() {
      await fetch("https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=5")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.detaliiMP = data)
        .catch(err => console.error(err.message))
    },
    async showData() {
      await this.getData()
      console.log(this.detaliiMP)
    }
  },
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="getData">Get Data</button>

  <button @click="showData">Console LogOut</button>

  <p v-for="item in detaliiMP">{{ item.first_name }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I was using async/await only on one function at a time, not for both in the same time (duuh). I'm trying to get the logic behind and I don't really understand why we need to use async/await for both functions in the same time? Thanks!